# Explanation of tilde in function arguments

Tags: r, plotly, lazy-evaluation, tilde

I try to understang how to plot cumulative lines animation with `plotly`. The code from "Plotly R Open Source Graphing Library" is below:

```
library(plotly)

accumulate_by <- function(dat, var) {
  var <- lazyeval::f_eval(var, dat)
  lvls <- plotly:::getLevels(var)
  dats <- lapply(seq_along(lvls), function(x) {
    cbind(dat[var %in% lvls[seq(1, x)], ], frame = lvls[[x]])
  })
  dplyr::bind_rows(dats)
}

df <- txhousing 
fig <- df %>%
  filter(year > 2005, city %in% c("Abilene", "Bay Area"))
fig <- fig %>% accumulate_by(~date)
```

1. *The main question* is to explain what happens when we pass the
   `~date` to the `accumulate_by` function. Which values `dat` and
   `var` variables will get? And how it works?
2. If I understand what values the `var` and `dat` variables take, it becomes clear what the `f_eval` function does, but now I don’t understand this.
3. What `plotly:::getLevels` is? I mean, I did not find any documentation about this function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. *The main question is to explain what happens when we pass the ~date
   to the accumulate_by function. Which values dat and var variables
   will get? And how it works?*

   `accumulate_by` will take whatever values of `dat` and `var` are passed to it, in that order.  What this means is if you pass `accumulate_by(Var1, Var2)` this is the same as `accumulate_by(dat = Var1, var = Var2)`.  This is called positional matching.

   As the code is written `fig` is your `dat` variable, since it comes into `accumulate_by` via the pipe (`%>%`) in the first position.  `~date` is your `var` variable, because it's in the second position.

   the `~` in front of date means "by", so "by date".

   What `accummlate_by` is actually doing is collecting all rows and all variables with a given date value in a new variable called `level`.  It's then progressing to the next date value and collecting all rows and variables for that date, plus all rows and variables for all the preceding values of date and giving that another value for `level`.  You can check `str(fig)` before and after applying `accumulate_by` to see that `fig` gets much longer (many more rows) and gains another variable called `level` after applying `accumulate_by`.
2. *If I understand what values the var and dat variables take, it
   becomes clear what the f_eval function does, but now I don’t
   understand this.*

   Addressed (I hope) in the answer to question 1.
3. *What plotly:::getLevels is? I mean, I did not find any documentation
   about this function.*

   The triple colon means "search entire package (in this case the package is `plotly`) including non-exported items in the package".
   What this means in practice is that lots of packages have "helper" functions and other utilities that aren't usually used by end-users.  Instead those helper functions are used by other functions in the package.  Helper functions aren't "exported", that is, generally available by just entering their names.  One can access them though, by using the `:::` triple colon.

   Because `getLevels` is not really intended to be used by `plotly` package users it likely isn't documented.